# HP QC ALM 12.21 API Reference Guide

Tags: alm, hp-performance-center

I would like to know the syntax for some of the API calls in ALM 12.21.
I need the API reference guide for ALM 12.21.
I couldn't find this elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

ALM is now a product of ***MicroFocus***.

REST API guide:

https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/12.55/api_refs/REST_TECH_PREVIEW/ALM_REST_API_TP.html

Comment: is this same for 12.2x?

Comment: @SujinSam, you can check for yourself, mF provides dox for all versions on that site.

Answer (score 0):

The 12.21 REST API docs can be downloaded from this page:

https://support.microfocus.com/kb/kmdoc.php?id=KM01722325

... click the **Attachment** link there.

This downloads a 770KB .zip that contains the HTML for the 12.21 REST API docs. If you don't want to give them a home in a web server, just unzip it and point your browser at [...]\REST\index.html (or, [...]/REST/index.html, if that's how you roll)

Comment: The companion "Tech Preview" HTML docs are available (as above) from:

https://support.microfocus.com/kb/kmdoc.php?id=KM01722328


Sorry, just assumed that'd be in there (facepalm)
Cheers,